# Django Model Reference to Multiple Foreign Key with Child Property

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Models of customer details with each customers having different payment modes (eg. cash, online transfer, etc...) :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    #some customer details

class Payment(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name='payments')
    payment_mode = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

And I would like to add a new Invoice Model to include the customer as well as the customer's payment modes.

```
class Invoice (models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name='payments')
    payment_mode = models.ForeignKey(Customer.payments.payment_mode, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

I am going to create an Invoice for a customer and will input the customer's available payment mode. But the the invoice's payment mode is giving me an AttributeError: 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'payment_mode'.

May I know how do I set up the reference to the customer's child data?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a valid field definition.

You can reference `Payment` directly

```
payment_mode = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

Comment: As the Payment Model has a foreign key to the Customer, I would like to have the payment in the invoice related to the selected customer only.

Comment: You have to validate the customer and payment_mode  before inserting into invoice table.

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea now. May I know how can I implement a new invoice in the admin form (with the ability to validate the customer first)?

Comment: You can make it work with inline form, you can refer [this](https://swapps.com/blog/working-with-nested-forms-with-django/)

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `Invoice` model even required? You have the same fields already in the existing models.
You can simply make a view to do this.
For example,

```py
def show_invoice(request, pk):
    # this pk value should be sent by your frontend and represents your Primary Key value for the current customer
    customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'some_html_page.html', {'customer': customer})
```

Now in your `some_html_page.html`, you can show the details you want using the 'context' to the render function (`{'customer': customer}`) we just passed.

Models in Django should be thought of as Tables in SQL; you are not supposed to make a new one every time you want to "infer" something, rather you should make them when you want to 'store' something (or normalize existing tables/models). The `Invoice` model does not do either of these two things.

You can give this a read to understand how to write views in Django [this.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something)

In the case where you really want to make an Invoice model you don't need to make a `payment_mode` field, since you're already pointing to the Customer model which is, in turn, pointing to the Payment model.